# How to group rows and extract mean values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
df =
    QUEUE_1   QUEUE_2   QUEUE_3   HOUR   TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME  TOTAL_WAIT_TIME
    ABC123    DEF656              7      20                  30
    ABC123                        7      22                  32
    DEF656    ABC123    FED456    8      15                  12
    FED456    DEF656              8      15                  16
```

I want to calculate the mean `TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME` and `TOTAL_WAIT_TIME` for each type of `QUEUE` (`ABC123`,`DEF656`,`FED456`) over hours.

The result should be this one:

```
result =
    QUEUE    HOUR   AVG_TOT_SERVICE_TIME   AVG_TOT_WAIT_TIME
    ABC123   7      21                     31
    ABC123   8      15                     12
    DEF656   7      20                     30
    DEF656   8      15                     14
    FED456   7      0                      0
    FED456   8      15                     14
```

This is my current code, but it does not seem to give the expected result. In particular, the values of `HOUR` are not ordered and the mean values of `TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME` and `TOTAL_WAIT_TIME` are not calculated properly.

```
cols = ['QUEUE', 'HOUR', 'TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME', 'TOTAL_WAIT_TIME']
result = pd.melt(
    df, ['HOUR', 'TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME', 'TOTAL_WAIT_TIME'],
    ['QUEUE_1', 'QUEUE_2', 'QUEUE_3'],
    value_name='QUEUE')[cols]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need first reshape your data by `melt` or `lreshape`:

```
result = pd.lreshape(df, {'QUEUE': ['QUEUE_1','QUEUE_2','QUEUE_3']})
print (result)
   HOUR  TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME  TOTAL_WAIT_TIME   QUEUE
0     7                  20               30  ABC123
1     7                  22               32  ABC123
2     8                  15               12  DEF656
3     8                  15               16  FED456
4     7                  20               30  DEF656
5     8                  15               12  ABC123
6     8                  15               16  DEF656
7     8                  15               12  FED456
```

Then `groupby` with `mean` and last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `MultiIndex` created from `unique` values of columns `QUEUE` and `HOUR`:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([result.QUEUE.dropna().unique(), 
                                  result.dropna().HOUR.unique()], names=['QUEUE','HOUR'])

print (result.groupby(['QUEUE','HOUR'])
             .mean()
             .reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
             .add_prefix('AVG_')
             .reset_index())

    QUEUE  HOUR  AVG_TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME  AVG_TOTAL_WAIT_TIME
0  ABC123     7                      21                   31
1  ABC123     8                      15                   12
2  DEF656     7                      20                   30
3  DEF656     8                      15                   14
4  FED456     7                       0                    0
5  FED456     8                      15                   14
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I force `FED456` appear for the `HOUR` equal to 7? The values of `TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME` and `TOTAL_WAIT_TIME` should be equal to 0 in such cases.

Comment: Also, I get an error `KeyError: 'QUEUE'`. Please notice that I have `QUEUE_1`,`QUEUE_2` and `QUEUE_3` in the original dataframe. I want to get unique column `QUEUE` with unique values, as I shown in the example.

Comment: I still have one doubt. Do you mean that I should firstly execute my code in order to get `result` and then execute yours? My original dataframe is called `df`, but I see only `result` in your code. Sorry, I haven't explained it well at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

***Steps:***

1) Use `pd.lreshape` to convert the `DF` from wide to long format for the column names starting with *QUEUE_X* and name that wholesome column as *QUEUE*.

2) Pivot the `DF` using `pivot_table` which uses `np.mean` as it's aggregating function by default.  Optionally fill missing values with 0.

3) Stack the obtained `DF` so that columns get enforced as the index resulting in a multi-index format. Add a char prefix and reset it's index.

---

```
df = pd.lreshape(df, {'QUEUE': df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('QUEUE')].tolist()})
piv_df = df.pivot_table(index=['QUEUE'], columns=['HOUR'], fill_value=0)
piv_df.stack().add_prefix('AVG_').reset_index()
```

[image]