# How to add columns with the average percent and average count to the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

This question is related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933319/how-to-group-rows-and-extract-mean-values). I have the following dataframe:

```
df =
    QUEUE_1   QUEUE_2   DAY   HOUR   TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME  TOTAL_WAIT_TIME   EVAL
    ABC123    DEF656    1     7      20                  30                1
    ABC123              1     7      22                  32                0
    DEF656    ABC123    1     8      15                  12                0
    FED456    DEF656    2     8      15                  16                1
```

I need to get the following dataframe (it's similar to the one I wanted to get in my previous question, but here I need to add 2 additional columns `AVG_COUNT_PER_DAY_HOUR` and `AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1`).

```
QUEUE    HOUR    AVG_TOT_SERVICE_TIME  AVG_TOT_WAIT_TIME  AVG_COUNT_PER_DAY_HOUR  AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1
ABC123   7       21                    31                 1                       50
ABC123   8       15                    12                 0.5                     100
DEF656   7       20                    30                 0.5                     100
DEF656   8       15                    14                 1                       50
FED456   7       0                     0                  0                       0
FED456   8       15                    14                 0.5                     100
```

The column `AVG_COUNT_PER_DAY_HOUR` should contain the average count of a corresponding `HOUR` value over days (`DAY`) grouped by `QUEUE`. For example, in `df`, in case of `ABC123`, the `HOUR` 7 appears 2 times for the `DAY` 1 and 0 times for the `DAY` 2. Therefore the average is 1. The same logic is applied to the `HOUR` 8. It appears 1 time in `DAY` 1 and 0 times in `DAY` 2 for `ABC123`. Therefore the average is 0.5.

The column `AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1` should contain the percent of `EVAL` equal to 1 over hours, grouped by `QUEUE`. For example, in case of `ABC123`, the `EVAL` is equal to 1 one time when `HOUR` is 7. It is also equal to 0 one time when `HOUR` is 7. So, `AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1` is 50 for `ABC123` and hour 7.

I use this approach:

```
df = pd.lreshape(aa, {'QUEUE': df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('QUEUE')].tolist()})
piv_df = df.pivot_table(index=['QUEUE'], columns=['HOUR'], fill_value=0)
result = piv_df.stack().add_prefix('AVG_').reset_index()
```

I get stuck with adding columns `AVG_COUNT_PER_DAY_HOUR` and `AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1`. For instance, to add the column `AVG_COUNT_PER_DAY_HOUR` I am thinking to use `.apply(pd.value_counts, 1).notnull().groupby(level=0).sum().astype(int)`, while for calculating `AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1` I am thinking to use `[df.EVAL==1].agg({'EVAL' : 'count'})`. However, don't know how to incorporate it into my current code in order to get correct solution.

UPDATE:

Perhaps it is easier to adopt this solution to what I need in this questions:

```
result = pd.lreshape(df, {'QUEUE': ['QUEUE_1','QUEUE_2']})

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([result.QUEUE.dropna().unique(), 
                                  result.dropna().DAY.unique(),
                                  result.HOUR.dropna().unique(), ], names=['QUEUE','DAY','HOUR'])

print (result.groupby(['QUEUE','DAY','HOUR'])
             .mean()
             .reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
             .add_prefix('AVG_')
             .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Steps:***

1) To compute *AVG_COUNT_PER_DAY_HOUR* :

With the help of [`pd.crosstab()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.crosstab.html), compute the distinct counts of *HOUR* *w.r.t* *DAYS* (so that we obtain cases for missing days) grouped by *QUEUE*.

`stack` the `DF` so that *HOUR* which was part of a hierarchical column before now gets positioned as an index, leaving just *DAYS* as columns. We take the mean columnwise after filling `NaNs` with 0.

2) To compute *AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1*:

After getting the pivoted frame (same as before) and also from the fact that mean would just give us the percentage change as those are simply binary in nature (1/0), we simply take *EVAL* from this `DF` and multiply it's result by 100 as means were computed while pivoting itself (default `agg`=`np.mean`).

Finally, we join all these frames.

---

***same as in the linked post:***

```
df = pd.lreshape(df, {'QUEUE': df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('QUEUE')].tolist()})
piv_df = df.pivot_table(index='QUEUE', columns='HOUR', fill_value=0).stack()
avg_tot = piv_df[['TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME', 'TOTAL_WAIT_TIME']].add_prefix("AVG_")
```

***additional portion:***

```
avg_cnt = pd.crosstab(df['QUEUE'], [df['DAY'], df['HOUR']]).stack().fillna(0).mean(1)
avg_pct = piv_df['EVAL'].mul(100).astype(int)
avg_tot.join(
    avg_cnt.to_frame("AVG_COUNT_PER_DAY_HOUR")
).join(avg_pct.to_frame("AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1")).reset_index()
```

[image]

---

`avg_cnt` looks like:

```
QUEUE   HOUR
ABC123  7       1.0
        8       0.5
DEF656  7       0.5
        8       1.0
FED456  7       0.0
        8       0.5
dtype: float64
```

`avg_pct` looks like:

```
QUEUE   HOUR
ABC123  7        50
        8         0
DEF656  7       100
        8        50
FED456  7         0
        8       100
Name: EVAL, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you please to briefly explain your code?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that before `pd.crosstab` I should run `df = pd.lreshape(df, {'QUEUE': df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('QUEUE')].tolist()})` ?

Comment: One more comment. When I run the original code taken from my previous thread (the one proposed by you), then I get different values of `AVG_TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME` and `AVG_TOTAL_WAIT_TIME`, while they must be the same. I refer to this code: `df = pd.lreshape(aa, {'QUEUE': df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('QUEUE')].tolist()})
piv_df = df.pivot_table(index=['QUEUE'], columns=['HOUR'], fill_value=0)
result = piv_df.stack().add_prefix('AVG_').reset_index()`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but I cannot understand why the original code taken from my previous thread (the one proposed by you) gives me different values of `AVG_TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME` and `AVG_TOTAL_WAIT_TIME`. May it happen that here you calculate mean values of these 2 columns by averaging them over `DAY` AND `HOUR`, while originally I wanted to average them over `HOUR`?

Comment: No, In the previous post you had included *QUEUE_3* which was omitted here. Hence, the discrepancy. If I've comprehended your question properly, then the solution would definitely work.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I am wrong, but I run this code on my real data and then I run the previous code on the same data, and get different results. I may show screenshots in the cart, if you have a free minute.

Comment: Bring it on. Let's fix this together. Attach those in your post.

Comment: Oh, I finally found an error. It was my fault. Just forgot to delete one line of code that performed a filtering. Thank you.